# archive artifacts for android apk jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins

I have an .apk file in build/output/APK/debug/debug_app.apk. I am able
    to generate built I want to Post-build Actions Archive and artifact
    it for that I wrote one command to go Project directory and then in
    artifact 
        I tried to add `build/output/APK/debug/*.APK` path but its not able to find path it say not found while .APK file is there. I want
    to archive and artifact APK file when build is complete please
    suggest me how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Note that Archive the artifacts has an Advanced section there is a checkbox "Treat include and exclude patterns as case sensitive", as I see the "APK" vs "apk" would fail to match if you have that checked.  Alternatively simply using build/output/APK/debug/*.* would get around that specific issue.

Please let me know if these suggestions help. :)

Comment: i tried  send notification with attach file but i am unable to receive email  but in console it show Sending email for trigger: Success

Comment: Hi MARSH, I don't believe your question is related to the original.